# How do get control of a base? Mission 9b: Establish Nod Presence tiberium sun

Tags: command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun

Here is the mission outline: http://guidesarchive.ign.com/guides/3851/nod_set/nod9b.htm

I would expect the base to be transfered to my control once my units are near it, but nothing happens. The buildings are red (my colour). If I destroy one of the buildings the red infantry that appears will attack me.

No engineers are given at the start of the mission.

How do I get control of the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Approach it from the south ramp that will usually activate the trigger that gives you control of the base if it doesn't happen move your units around the the ramp area or other areas at the edge of the base. Make sure the weed eaters and harvester came to the base as well if you do all this it should transfer to you.

2)If all this fails you have to restart the mission as it probably suffered from a rare glitch.

Comment: I tried the west approach and suddenly that worked. Maybe the first building you spot has to be the mvc? Thanks for the help bro.